# Quiz app keeps crashing when shuffling array and selecting number of questions. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio-2.2

I have an array of 300+ questions (With 2 more arrays for answers & correct answers). But when I try to create my "Test Mode" I would like to choose only 110 questions (of those 300 ). Before this code I'm attaching, it worked fine, but pulls the 300+ questions (and answers etc.) With this new code (That I'm pasting).. when I click the Test Mode, the app crashes.

```
public List<String> shuffleChapterRandomTest() {
final List<String> randomQuestions = Arrays.asList(chapterRandomTestQuestions);
Collections.shuffle(randomQuestions);

final List<String> randomCorrects = Arrays.asList(chapterRandomTestcorrectanswers);
Collections.shuffle(randomCorrects);

final List<String[]> randomChoices =  Arrays.asList(chapterRandomTestmultiplechoices);

return shuffleChapterRandomTest().subList(0, 115);}


public static[] String shuffledPositionChapterRandomTest;

private String chapterRandomTestQuestions[] = {
    “Question 1”,//001
    “Question 2”//02
};

private String[][] chapterRandomTestmultiplechoices = {
    {“answer1”, "answer2”, "answer3”}, //001
    {"answer1”, "answer2”, "answer3”},//02
};

private String[] chapterRandomTestcorrectanswers = {
 “answer1”  //01
 “answer2” //02
};

public int getChapterRandomTestLength() {
return chapterRandomTestQuestions.length}

public getChapterRandomTestQuestion(String a) {
return chapterRandomTestQuestions[Integer.parseInt(a)];}

public String getChapterRandomTestChoice(String index, int num) {
return chapterRandomTestmultiplechoices[Integer.parseInt(index)][num - 1];}

public String getChapterRandomTestCorrectAnswer(String a) {
return chapterRandomTestcorrectanswers[Integer.parseInt(a)];}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an infinite loop in your code:

> ```
> public List<String> shuffleChapterRandomTest() {
>     ...
>     return shuffleChapterRandomTest().subList(0, 115);}
> ```

I'm not sure exactly what you *want* to return here, but it's definitely not `shuffleChapterRandomTest()`. My best guess is that you want to return `randomQuestions`, though of course this would just ignore `randomCorrects` and `randomChoices`.

Comment: So I fixed the code to be something like this:
`public List<String> shuffleChapterRandomTest() {
        final List<String> randomQuestions = Arrays.asList(chapterRandomTestQuestions);
        Collections.shuffle(randomQuestions);

        return randomQuestions.subList(0, 115);
 ` 
But it crashed again. And, about the infinite loop, I honestly don't know what to do. I bought the code almost finished. So I don't know exactly how to tune it.

Comment: The answer always starts with reading the crash report from the logcat, which will generally tell you what line the crash happened on and what type of error it encountered. This time, my guess is that `randomQuestions` is less than 115 elements long.